# parse server not accepting postgres connections

Tags: node.js, postgresql, parse-server

Issue Description

Error While Running requet on parse-server

I started with parse-server and trying to pass postgres uri for Database URI,
eg. parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI postgres://user:password@localhost/db_name , it starts without a issue but when i try out a curl request to test it says

error: Uncaught internal server error. Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb

it accepts postgres url while starting but then it works internally with mongo db instead of postgres
Steps to reproduce

Try a fresh clone and npm install

Set the database uri to postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/db_name and try a curl request to create a object
eg.
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"sce":false}' http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
Expected Results

{
"objectId": "some-obj-id",
"createdAt": "time-stamp"
}

Actual Outcome

error: Uncaught internal server error. Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb ...

Environment Setup

```
Server
    parse-server version (Be specific! Don't say 'latest'.) : 2.3.6
    Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04
    Hardware: Local System
    Localhost or remote server? (AWS, Heroku, Azure, Digital Ocean, etc): localhost

Database
    MongoDB version: Not MongoDb
    Postgres version - 9.6.2
    Storage engine: none
    Hardware: Local System
    Localhost or remote server? (AWS, mLab, ObjectRocket, Digital Ocean, etc): Localhost
```

Logs/Trace

{"level":"error","message":"Uncaught internal server error. Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb\n ......}

Comment: [You have opened an issue against the library](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/3595), there is no point asking it here at the same time.

Comment: There is a https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/2871 adding pg feature in the library, please check it.

Comment: So you need to chase it there, nobody will help you here with that.